# Происхождение фамилии Стихальский

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Связана ли фамилия *Стихальский* со словом *тихий*? Какова ее этимология?

Comment: Может быть и «Стих — юж. зап. «полоска плетеная, строка, дорожка в лаптях"» (Словарь В. Даля 1882, 4, с. 332–333). Или в смысле «иногда на него находил философский стих».

Comment: @shampar всё может быть )

Answer (score 1):

Нашлась вот такая информация (правда, не знаю, насколько ее можно считать достоверной):

Фамилия Стихальский происходит от прозвища *Стихалый*. Так в старину называли нервного, причудливого, своенравного человека. Кроме того, в некоторых говорах таким прозвищем нарекали человека, который знал много легенд и былин.

Менее правдоподобна версия о происхождении от канонического мужского имени Стефан (от древнегреческого *stefane* – «венок»; женские — Стефания, Степанида). Сама же фамилия восходит к его просторечному варианту – Стихаля.
В этом случае фамилия Стихальский относится к немногочисленной группе матронимических фамилий (матронимический — прозванный по имени матери).
[**Происхождение фамилии Стихальский**](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, я прочитал это тоже! Но хотелось бы что-нибудь авторского, а не от ноунейма, поэтому и решил спросить :)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova А разве вот здесь неправильно? https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/maruso/2969/metronìmico и https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/maruso/2805/matronyme

Comment: Дико непривычно! http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC Матро́ним (иногда — ма́тчество) — часть родового имени, которая присваивается ребёнку по имени матери. Матроним, передаваемый от матери, является противоположностью отчества (патронима), передаваемого от отца.
Матроним — Википедия
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Матроним